# How do I change the Cassandra topology + snitch in a multi AZ cluster?

Tags: cassandra, database-migration

I have a 9 nodes Cassandra v3.11 cluster in one availability zone with SimpleSnitchStrategy.

I want to change the snitch strategy to GossipingPropertyFileSnitch and the topology to be multi AZ like this:
3 nodes in AZ-A,
3 nodes in AZ-B,
 3 nodes in AZ-C.

**How should I do the migration?**
Move the nodes first and change the snitch strategy or
change the snitch strategy and then move the nodes?

Comment: A friendly note to let you know that Stack Overflow is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. Your question is more suited to dba.stackexchange.com. If you tag it `cassandra` or post the link to your question here, I'd be happy to help. Cheers!

Comment: Post added here:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314862/how-do-i-change-the-cassandra-topology-snitch-in-a-multi-az-cluster

Comment: Awesome! I've responded to you there. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting here that the question is a better fit for [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra).

I've posted a response in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314862/. Cheers!